# Redux thunk with rendering using App class

Tags: reactjs, redux, native, redux-thunk

Redux thunk with rendering using App class - I am using react-native and redux thunk to call the dispatcher via componentDidMount of App class and receiving errors "props is not defined" and "Unable to find module for EventDispatcher".
Would request for further help on this from experts.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './configureStore';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

const store = configureStore();

const rnredux = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => rnredux);
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Platform, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchPeopleFromAPI} from './actions'


class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPeople();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native! & Redux</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={props.getPeople} style={styles.buttonText}>
          <Text>Fetch Data</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        {
          isFetching && <Text>Loading</Text>
        }
        {
          people.length? (
            people.map((person,index) => {
              return (
                <View key={index}>
                 <Text>Name: {person.breedName}</Text>
                </View>
              )
            })
           ) : null
          }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const {people, isFetching} = props.people
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  buttonText: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    height:60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
});

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    people: state.people
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    getPeople: () => dispatch(fetchPeopleFromAPI())
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

Comment: you just missed `this` in  `<TouchableHighlight onPress={props.getPeople} style={styles.buttonText}>`. add `onPress={this.props.getPeople}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part from your code completely:

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    getPeople: () => dispatch(fetchPeopleFromAPI())
  }
}
```

in your export statement amend into:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
 { fetchPeopleFromAPI }
)(App)
```

and finally in your `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPeopleFromAPI();
  }
```

Comment: Your recommendation works like butter, but is not able to solve the performance problem because the problem seems to be with fetch and res.json() ...

Comment: You mentioned issues with dispatching in your description, nothing about fetch and performance. Furthermore, the way I suggested does not have any negative impact in fetching data.

Comment: The issue is not with dispatching, it is with rendering and .map function.

Comment: can you be more specific as I have lost track? what's the error in your console? If your problem is that your array is not yet populated by the response from the server, you can try to add right below the render function something like this `if (people.length === 0) return <div>...Loading</div>` and when your array is populated that div will be substituted with the `View` component

Comment: The problem is either with res.json() within fetch or .map function within render(), because the data coming from server has no performance problem. If you look in my code.."Loading" thing has been included already ... but .json or .map takes too long to display the data